# Transpose table partially

Tags: excel, transpose, powerquery, m

I have a CSV-file containing information about some production batches. When loaded into Excels PowerQuery editor, the table looks like this:

```
Batch    Date         RawMaterial1    RawMaterial2    RawMaterial3    Amount1    Amount2    Amount3
123      01.01.2020   Fe              Cr              Ni              70         19         11
234      01.02.2020   Fe              Cr              Ni              72         17          9
```

To make this table more readable, I'm looking for a way to transpose it just partially to transform it into a format like this:

```
Batch    Date         RawMaterials    Amounts
123      01.01.2020   Fe              70
                      Cr              19
                      Ni              11
234      01.02.2020   Fe              72
                      Cr              17
                      Ni              11
```

Is there a way to realize this with PowerQueryM alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

Unpivots all columns but first two

Duplicate the data column

Change the column type to number to force an error on the non numerical columns

Change all errors into something recognizable, like 999999999999

Filter based on that into two tables, and add an index to each table

Merge the two tables together

Add new column, using index to see if Batch is same as prior row to eliminate duplicates

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Date", "Batch"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value", "Value - Copy"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Value - Copy", type number}}),
#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type", {{"Value - Copy", 999999999999999}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Errors", each ([#"Value - Copy"] = 999999999999999)),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Errors", each ([#"Value - Copy"] <> 999999999999999)),
Index1 = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
Index2 = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows2", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Index2,{"Index"},Index1,{"Index"},"Index3",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Index3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Index3", {"Value"}, {"Value.1"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Index3",{"Attribute", "Value - Copy"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Batch.1", each if [Index] = 0 then [Batch] else if #"Removed Columns"{[Index]-1}[Batch] = [Batch] then null else [Batch]),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Date.1", each if [Index] = 0 then [Date] else if #"Removed Columns"{[Index]-1}[Batch] = [Batch] then null else [Date]),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Batch", "Date", "Index"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Batch.1", "Date.1", "Value.1", "Value"})
in  #"Reordered Columns"
```

Comment: Awesome job! This works. As a bonus I would love to know if you may change duplicate texts into an empty string (if they are in consecutive rows, see initial question). This would boost readability of the table once more.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite a bit more simply:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],,
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Batch", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"RawMaterial1", type text}, {"RawMaterial2", type text}, {"RawMaterial3", type text}, {"Amount1", Int64.Type}, {"Amount2", Int64.Type}, {"Amount3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Batch", "Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Type", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Character Transition", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Character Transition"[Type]), "Type", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

1. Unpivot all but the first two columns.
2. Split the Attribute column into the text part and index part (in the GUI: Transform > Split Column > By Non-Digit to Digit).
3. Pivot back on the text part column (choose Don't Aggregate in the Pivot Column Advanced options).

Answer (score 1):

First of all a big thank you to @horseyride. I learned a lot from your suggested code. Sadly when I tried to add the date-column to the unpivot area as well I found a little flaw in the code. But thanks to the lessons I learned from it I was able to produce a slightly more generic version which basically follows the same algorithm.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Unpivot Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Batch"}, "Attribut", "Wert"),
    Filter1 = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivot Columns", each ([Attribut] <> "Amount1" and [Attribut] <> "Amount2" and [Attribut] <> "Amount3")),
    ModFilter1 = Table.AddColumn(Filter1, "Benutzerdefiniert", each if [Attribut] = "Date" then [Attribut] else [Wert], type text),
    Filter2 = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivot Columns", each ([Attribut] <> "RawMaterial1" and [Attribut] <> "RawMaterial2" and [Attribut] <> "RawMaterial3")),
    #"IndexFilter1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(ModFilter1, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"IndexFilter2" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Filter2, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Join Filtered Indexes" = Table.NestedJoin(IndexFilter1,{"Index"},IndexFilter2,{"Index"},"IndexFilter2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expand Joined Column" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Join Filtered Indexes", "IndexFilter2", {"Wert"}, {"IndexFilter2.Wert"}),
    #"Remove Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expand Joined Column",{"Index", "Attribut", "Wert"}),
    #"Rename Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Remove Columns",{{"Benutzerdefiniert", "Attribut"}, {"IndexFilter2.Wert", "Wert"}})
in
    #"Rename Columns"
```

I keep horseyrides answer checked as the right answer as he solves my initial question as it was.